# CSS Resources/ Tutorials

Tags: css, resources

I'm looking for resources to brush up on my CSS skills.  I can do basic positioning and whatnot, it just seems as though resources aimed at CSS are either very simple with very important details left out, or on advanced topics that I'm not really looking for (cross-browser round images, for example).

Basically, I usually have an idea of how I want it to look, however getting it to look how I envision it is another matter entirely.  What sources would you suggest, be it book or interwebs?

Comment: Amazon is a great place to hunt for good resources. Check out the reviews of each book with a critical eye. This isn't really on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see how it is off-topic, a programmer asking other programmers for a good place to start.  I could have done much worse and just put my code out and whined for other programmers to fix it for me.  Rather, I'm trying to learn how to do it myself.  Not good enough for Stack Overflow?

Comment: See [What shouldn't I ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for more info.

Comment: That's really a pretty broad question. [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/) is good for all levels, [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/tag/css/) has good information on technique, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS) is of course a good reference with tutorials, etc. Personally, I'd try to pickup [a grid system](http://www.thegridsystem.org/) and or [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). That's where you'll learn something.

Comment: And, y'know, the [specifications too](http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_CSS).

Comment: Ok, I've not seen A List Apart's website yet, I'll read that as well.  I've actually been using Bootstrap for a while, I just end up in situations where I set CSS properties and because of some specifics it doesn't work as intended. I suppose I just need to sit down for an entire day an read the specifics on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTMLDog](http://www.htmldog.com/) is how I learned HTML/CSS.

Also did a quick Google search and found this:
http://www.noupe.com/css/css-layouts-40-tutorials-tips-demos-and-best-practices.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess u have basic of css and want improve it ? if u have basic i think easy to improve it so u must have imagination about making something "*epic*" and unwittingly u will improve ur css "skill"

so below link when i frist learn css :

simple basic but imprtant :
 1. https://www.google.co.id/ < epic one

1. http://www.w3schools.com/

   Tips and Trick :
2. http://www.script-tutorials.com/
3. http://djogzs.blogspot.com/ * indonesian version,u need to translate
   with google translate but u will found epic tutorials there
4. The Other i just hold CTRL + U or F12 on the website which i like it
   XD

That is my opinion how to learn css and improve it,Cheerrsss ;))

**Edited:** "i think u not need book or artikel,because my experice my css improve 60% from click f12 XD and 20% from artikel on web site 20% again i dont know >_< *but u must have basic frist"